# Magento 2 : Enable only Paypal Payflow Pro

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal-payments-pro

How can I enable Paypal Payflow pro in Magento 2. At present when I tried to enable Paypal Payflow pro,then one more payment method PayPal Express Checkout Payflow Edition is also enabled.

Which I dont want. 
Please help me for this.

Comment: You can't enable Payflow Pro without Payflow Pro Express Checkout, because Express it's a part of Payflow Pro

Comment: What if you set "display on shopping cart" and "display on product page" to "no"?

Comment: @MatHellums yes I can set those settings but still that was display on checkout.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update your payment settings by completing the following steps.

1. Select **Configure** under Payflow Pro.
2. Select **Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout** to show more options.
3. Select **Advanced Settings** to show even more options.
4. Select the **Payment Applicable From** dropdown and choose "Specific Countries".
5. De-select all countries in the **Countries Payment Applicable From** select list.
6. Confirm there are *no* countries selected.
7. Select **Save Config**.
8. Clear cache.

By making the payment option unavailable in any country, the option will no longer appear during checkout.  You can also choose to not show the payment option on the product and shopping cart page to *remove* the option altogether.

[image]